# Cannot convert partially known tensor in TensorFlow/TFLearn

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

I'm a beginner to TensorFlow and still trying to figure out how it works, so I'm not sure if the error is a problem with my architecture or something more basic -- here I'm trying to train a siamese neural network (we feed a left and right input into left and right NN with identical weights, and try to map it to feature vectors that have small distance if the inputs are similar and large distance if the inputs are different).

The error I get occurs at the regression step:

```py
  File "siamese.py", line 59, in <module>
    network = regression(y_pred, optimizer='adam',
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.py", line 63, in __init__
    best_val_accuracy=best_val_accuracy)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py", line 120, in __init__
    clip_gradients)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py", line 646, in initialize_training_ops
    ema_num_updates=self.training_steps)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tflearn/summaries.py", line 236, in add_loss_summaries
    loss_averages_op = loss_averages.apply([loss] + other_losses)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/moving_averages.py", line 292, in apply
    colocate_with_primary=(var.op.type == "Variable"))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/slot_creator.py", line 106, in create_zeros_slot
    val = array_ops.zeros(primary.get_shape().as_list(), dtype=dtype)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1071, in zeros
    shape = ops.convert_to_tensor(shape, dtype=dtypes.int32, name="shape")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 628, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 198, in _tensor_shape_tensor_conversion_function
    "Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: %s" % s)
ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (?,)
```

I don't know how to resolve this problem if the first dimension needs to be `None` for the batch size (correct me if I'm wrong).

Relevant parts of the code are below:

```py
BATCH_SIZE=100
def contrastive_loss(y_pred, y_true, margin=1.0):
    return tf.mul(1-y_true, tf.square(y_pred)) + tf.mul(y_true, tf.square(tf.maximum((margin-y_pred),0)))

## Load dataset
f = h5py.File('./data/paired_training_data.hdf','r')
X1 = f["train_X1"]
X2 = f["train_X2"]
Y = f["train_Y_paired"]

## Inputs: 1 example (phoneme pair), dropout probability
inp_sound1 = input_data(shape=[None, 1, N_MFCC_CHANNELS, N_IN_CHANNELS])
networkL = conv_1d(inp_sound1, reuse=None, scope="conv1d")
networkL = max_pool_1x6(networkL)
networkL = fully_connected(networkL, n_units=N_FULLY_CONN, activation='relu', scope="fc1")
networkL = dropout(networkL, .5) # unshared?
networkL = fully_connected(networkL, n_units=N_FULLY_CONN, activation='relu', scope="fc2")

inp_sound2 = input_data(shape=[None, 1, N_MFCC_CHANNELS, N_IN_CHANNELS])
networkR = conv_1d(inp_sound2, reuse=True, scope="conv1d")
networkR = max_pool_1x6(networkR)
networkR = fully_connected(networkR, n_units=N_FULLY_CONN, activation='relu', reuse=True, scope="fc1")
networkR = dropout(networkR, .5)
networkR = fully_connected(networkR, n_units=N_FULLY_CONN, activation='relu', reuse=True, scope="fc2")

l2_loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.sub(networkL, networkR)), 1)
y_pred = tf.sqrt(l2_loss)
#y_true = input_data(shape=[None])

## Training
network = regression(y_pred, optimizer='adam',
            loss=contrastive_loss, learning_rate=0.0001, to_one_hot=False)
model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit([X1, X2], Y, n_epoch=10, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, show_metric=True, validation_set=0.1)
```

Any help -- especially with understanding how to debug these issues on my own in the future -- would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would start by changing `reuse=None` to `reuse=True` (or `False`). You **can** force given `BATCH_SIZE`, substituting `None` with `BATCH_SIZE` everywhere.

Comment: @sygi I set the first layer `reuse=None` because I got an error that the scope "conv1d" doesn't exist yet -- the second layer does have `reuse=True`, though. Let me know if this is still the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Also, if I substitute `None` with `BATCH_SIZE`, TFLearn [automatically appends](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/tflearn/layers/core.py#L73) a first dimension `None` (so that my 4D vector becomes 5D, and then it no longer works with the conv layer).

Comment: Try removing `None`, then? My guess it is that is always appends `None`, and if you have two it complains.
As far as `reuse` is concerned, this parameter expects bool (see [docs](http://tflearn.org/layers/conv/#convolution-1d)) -- it is possible that `None` will serve as `False`, but I'd change it to be sure it is not the problem.

Comment: Sadly, removing `None` still produces the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like TensorFlow cannot infer the shape of your `contrastive_loss`. Try to call `set_shape` in your `contrastive_loss` function if you know its output shape in advance:

```
def contrastive_loss(y_pred, y_true, margin=1.0):
  loss = tf.mul(1-y_true, tf.square(y_pred)) + tf.mul(y_true, tf.square(tf.maximum((margin-y_pred),0)))
  loss.set_shape([...])
  return loss
```

Comment: I tried setting the shape of the loss and the shape of `y_pred` (since it complained without it) to `[BATCH_SIZE,]`, but this causes more mismatches that I don't know how to resolve -- Adam/ScalarSummary throws an error that `tags and values not the same shape: [] != [100]`.

Comment: I guess the shape of `y_pred` would not be [BATCH_SIZE,], otherwise there is not dimension for the actual data.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? I assume it would just be a vector of BATCH_SIZE scalars (0-dimensional numbers)? `y_pred` just needs to be the distance between the vectors outputted by the left and right networks.

Comment: If it is a vector of BATCH_SIZE scalars, then its shape should be [BATCH_SIZE, 1]

Comment: It still has the same `Adam/ScalarSummary` error, now `[] != [100,1]`.